# Text me or text TO me?

Tags: prepositions

What's more natural?

> Text me when the teacher comes.

or

> Text **TO** me when the teacher comes.

?

Is the preposition 'to' in this cases necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "text *something* to *someone*" or "text *someone*"

> Text me when you get home!

or

> Text your number to me later!

This also works

> Text (to) me your number later!

Answer (score 1):

"Text" can be a noun or a verb. This is not uncommon in English - for example,  *to fish* is the verb for catching *a fish*. Likewise, *to text* is the verb for sending *a text*.

You could say either:

- Text me
- Send me a text